# Record and later check running services

Tags: monitoring

In a presentation, I saw a command line tool mentioned that is able to record the running services (and the listening ports opened by them) as a baseline and later check against that baseline and report deviations.

Unfortunately, I don't remember the name of the tool, just, that it was written in Go (IIRC). Somehow I seem to use the wrong search terms and thus can't find it via a google search.

What is the name of this tool?

Comment: We've so far established that it's not Grafana or Prometheus.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I found it, it's [goss](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491899/1131)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the tool is [goss](https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss)!

From its README:

> What is Goss?
>
> Goss is a YAML based serverspec alternative tool for validating a server’s configuration. It eases the process of writing tests by allowing the user to generate tests from the current system state. Once the test suite is written they can be executed, waited-on, or served as a health endpoint.